# ERROR: null value in column violates not-null constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-insert, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE medico
    (num_cedula serial NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     nome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     especialidade varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(num_cedula));

CREATE TABLE consulta
    (num_cedula serial NOT NULL,
     num_doente serial NOT NULL,
     data_consulta date NOT NULL,
     nome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     CHECK(EXTRACT(DOW FROM data_consulta) NOT IN (6,0)),
     UNIQUE(num_doente,data_consulta,nome),
     FOREIGN KEY(nome) REFERENCES instituicao(nome) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
     FOREIGN KEY(num_cedula) REFERENCES medico(num_cedula) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
     PRIMARY KEY(num_cedula,num_doente,data_consulta));

CREATE TABLE analise
    (num_analise serial NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     especialidade varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     num_cedula serial ,
     num_doente serial ,
     data_analise date ,
     data_registo date NOT NULL,
     nome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     quant integer NOT NULL,
     inst varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT fk_analise FOREIGN KEY(num_cedula,num_doente,data_analise) REFERENCES consulta(num_cedula,num_doente,data_consulta) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
     FOREIGN KEY(inst) REFERENCES instituicao(nome) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
     PRIMARY KEY(num_analise));
```

This is my code but when I try to insert another "analise" with num_cedula,num_doente,data_analise as NULL it gives me this error ("ERROR:  null value in column "num_cedula" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (32, Ortopedia, null, null, null, 2019-12-02, glicemia, 176, Instituicao1).
SQL state: 23502") and I don't really know why.
Also, this is the insert code I used:

```
INSERT INTO analise VALUES(32,'Ortopedia',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2019-12-02','glicemia',176,'Instituicao1');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `serial` datatype just does not allow `null` values. The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) explains what happens under the hood when declaring a `serial` (emphasis is mine):

> Thus, we have created an integer column and arranged for its default values to be assigned from a sequence generator. **A `NOT NULL` constraint is applied** to ensure that a null value cannot be inserted.

I don't think that you really want `serial` here. The use case for that datatype is to create an auto-incremented column. You could probably use `int` instead, that would avoid the problem you are getting here.